# Php mail() send short messages and do not send big messages

Tags: php, email

Before this I am sorry for my bad English
The problem is that this code

```
    $headers  = "From: $from\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
    $headers .= "Reply-To: $replyTo\r\n";
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from\r\n";

    $message = wordwrap($message, 68);
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)) 
        return true;
    else 
        return false;
```

Send mail, for example, when $message = 'asasasasasasas'
and doesn't send when it's more long!
I'm working on my VPS and there are many other project where it works greatly, even if the $message is big.
What am I doing wrong?

PS: mail() return true

PS2: /var/log/maillog says OK:

```
mail() on [/var/www/.../Controller.php:213]: To: vla*****ss@gmail.com -- Headers: From: info@mydomain.ru  Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64    Reply-To: info@mydomain.ru  Return-Path: info@mydomain.ru
```

---

UPD New testing shows that if i delete adresses like ttt.domain.ru in message mail() sended greatly... i can't understand..

Comment: To add to that check the php mailer class.